# Как заставить пример с анимацией работать в safari?

Tags: вёрстка, css3, css-animation

блик должен ездить вдоль всей кнопки, в сафари этого не происходит

```
    button::after {
    content: "";
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 450%;
    height: 1200%;
    border-radius: 100%;
    border: 40px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7);
    animation: btn-shiny 5s ease-in-out infinite running;
    -webkit-animation: btn-shiny 5s ease-in-out infinite running;
}

@keyframes btn-shiny {
    0%  {
        margin: -80% 0 0 -86%;
    }
    100% {
        margin: -80% 0 0 90%
    }
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/1mq7gxtp/1/

Comment: блик должен ездить вдоль всей кнопки, в сафари этого не происходит

Comment: Добавьте это в сам вопрос.

Comment: Ну и за что закрыли?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Предлагаю сделать в качестве фона градиент и анимировать его положение.

[Есть статья](http://css.yoksel.ru/animation-for-gradients/), где говорится, что поддержка анимации позиции делается без проблем, а также приводится описание, как сделать анимацию цветов.

https://jsfiddle.net/1mq7gxtp/8/

```css
button {
    width: 200px;
    height: 50px;
    background: #000000; /* Old browsers */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(-45deg, #000000 30%, #acacac 30%, #acacac 40%, #000000 40%); /* FF3.6-15 */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(-45deg, #000000 30%,#acacac 30%,#acacac 40%,#000000 40%); /* Chrome10-25,Safari5.1-6 */
    background: linear-gradient(135deg, #000000 30%,#acacac 30%,#acacac 40%,#000000 40%); /* W3C, IE10+, FF16+, Chrome26+, Opera12+, Safari7+ */
    color: #fff;
    overflow: hidden;
    vertical-align: middle;
    line-height: 42px;
    -webkit-animation: btn-shiny 5s linear infinite;
    animation: btn-shiny 5s linear infinite;
}

@-webkit-keyframes btn-shiny {
    0%  {
        background-position: -100px 0;
    }
    100% {
        background-position: 300px 0;
    }
}

@keyframes btn-shiny {
    0%  {
        background-position: -100px 0;
    }
    100% {
        background-position: 300px 0;
    }
}
```

```html
<button>button</button>
```

Comment: @АндрейТаланин, ответ дополнен.

Answer (score 1):

http://caniuse.com/#search=css-animation

```
@-webkit-keyframes btn-shiny {
    0%  {
        margin: -80% 0 0 -86%;
    }
    100% {
        margin: -80% 0 0 90%
    }
}
```

И ещё, возможно, убрать `running`:

```
-webkit-animation: btn-shiny 5s ease-in-out infinite;
```

https://jsfiddle.net/1mq7gxtp/4/

Comment: В сафари 5, 6 не работает, но как же так? Если исходить из справки can i use, то получается, что это будет работать начиная с 8-ой версии, а более простой пример, такой https://jsfiddle.net/1mq7gxtp/ работает и в 5-ой, и в 6-ой версии.

Comment: @АндрейТаланин, во-первых, у анимации псевдоэлементов поддержка другая. Ещё можно поэксперементировать с одним или двума двоеточиями - насколько я помню, поддержка анимаций по ним (`:after`, `::after`) может отличаться в одном и том же браузере. Во-вторых, ты это чудо ещё и к `button` применяешь - попробуй для начала на `div`. Лучше страться не собирать за один раз полный комплект граблей :)